# Para que serve o :: (dois-pontos duplos) no AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angular, terminologia

Vi que em alguma pergunta do SO em Inglês um código AngularJS que estava usando dois-pontos duplos antes da variável.

Exemplo:

```
{{ ::nome_variavel }}
```

O normal costuma ser:

```
{{ nome_variavel }}
```

Qual é a diferença entre ambos? Qual é a diferença da primeira sintaxe em relação à segunda?

Comment: Exemplo - https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Complementando as respostas tentando explicar **Por que** e **Como** devemos usar a expressão.

---

#### Métodos de uso

Além do uso clássico com `{{::meuModelo}}` também pode ser usada através da diretiva `ngBind`: `<span ng-bind="::meuValor"></span>`

#### Por que usar?

Cada vez que fazemos a declaração de `{{meuValor}}` na view, um novo `watcher` é gerado. Em todo ciclo de `digest()` o AngularJS irá comparar o valor antigo do watcher com o novo valor e fazer a atualização, caso sejam diferentes. Quando usamos `::` estamos dizendo ao `AngularJS` para não reavaliar aquele `watcher` e isso irá aumentar a velocidade da aplicação, uma vez que haverá um menor número `watchers` a ser analisado.

#### Exemplos de uso

Devemos usar *OneWay Databind* ou `::` sempre que tivermos certeza de que um determinado dado não irá sofrer alteração dentro da aplicação, se houver alguma possibilidade de o dado poder ser alterado, deverá ser mantido seu uso padrão.

O uso mais comum é junto da diretiva `ngRepeat`, que é a que mais gera número de `watchers` e também há um modo de uso diferenciado, uma vez que podemos aplicar não só ao valor de um objeto de uma array, como a uma array inteira. Veja:

```
$scope.listaEndereco = [
    {id: 1, cidade: 'São Paulo', Estado: 'SP'},
    {id: 2, cidade: 'Rio de Janeiro', Estado: 'RJ'},
    {id: 3, cidade: 'Curitiba', Estado: 'PR'},
    ...
]

<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="endereco in $scope.listaEndereco track by endereco.id">{{endereco.cidade}}</li>
</ul>
```

Neste exemplo, se você tem certeza de que os dados dos endereços, como o nome da cidade, não puderem ser alterados, você pode usar: `{{::endereco.cidade}}`

No mesmo exemplo, se você também tem certeza de que a lista inteira de endereços não irá sofrer alterações, você pode combinar e ter um código assim:

```
<li ng-repeat="endereco in ::$scope.listaEndereco track by ::endereco.id">{{::endereco.cidade}}</li>
```

Deste modo todo o escopo será desconsiderado do ciclo e não só o valor do nome da cidade unicamente.

Isso é muito útil quando se trabalha com listas grandes e com o uso do `ngRepeat`, que é o maior impactante na geração de `watchers`.

Answer (score 13):

O termo se chama *one-time binding*. Da documentação do Angular:

> Uma expressão que começa com :: é considerada uma expressão de execução única. Estas expressões são avaliadas até seu valor se considerar estabilizado, o que acontece após o primeiro ciclo `digest()` caso o valor seja diferente de *undefined*.

Uma expressão é considerada estabilizada quando qualquer valor é retornado no ciclo `digest()`. Caso isso não aconteça, um monitor (*watcher*) fica reavaliando a expressão até que esta seja resolvida.

[Fonte](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression).

Comment: "Valor estabilizado" significa que passou de `undefined` para qualquer coisa?

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Adicionei a resposta à resposta. =)

Answer (score 9):

É o [OneTimeBinding](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression). Isso indica que assim que esse valor puder ser definido pelo *framework* ele já deve renderizar o conteúdo e não deve ficar tentando recalculá-lo. Assim ele se desliga do vínculo estabelecido (*unbind*). Note que o desligamento só ocorre quando tiver um valor definido.

Se não fizer isso ele ficará procurando o valor e pegará atualizações ocorridas no modelo, o que nem sempre é desejável. Pior ainda quando se sabe que valores não serão alterados. Não tem porque ele ficar insistindo em procurar por atualização. Obviamente um efeito interessante é uma melhor performance

Na documentação acima tem o algoritmo usado para definir quando deve parar.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 3):

**Qual é a diferença entre ambos? Qual é a diferença da primeira sintaxe em relação à segunda?**

O "::" é chamado de **One-time binding**, a diferença é a capacidade de processar dados uma vez e deixá-lo persistir sem ser afetado por atualizações futuro modelo. Veja o exemplo da documentação: https://plnkr.co/edit/6WRPadO6HVzzNXiNXQve?p=preview

Referências:

- [Speeding up AngularJS](https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/speeding-up-angular-js-with-simple-optimizations/135)
- [AngularJs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression)