# Comparar e atualizar dados de uma tabela HTML com dados retornados via JSON?

Tags: angularjs

Problema: Tenho uma tabela que é populada por dados vindos de multiplos arquivos JSON, até ai nenhum problema. A questão é que, preciso atualizar os dados caso os valores contidos no JSON sejam diferentes do que está na tabela, mas sem alterar a ordem dos itens.

Todo esse processo deve preferencialmente ser feito utilizando somente AngularJS.

Se um código (symbol) que veio no JSON não existir na tabela eu o adiciono, se já existir eu atualizo. No momento só tenho concluido o código abaixo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br" ng-app="money">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <title>BMF&Bovespa</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="assets/lib/angular.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            .green {
                color: green;
            }
            .red {
                color: red;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            angular.module("money", []);
            angular.module("money").controller("moneyController", function ($scope, $http, $interval) {

                var papeis = ['ABEaV3.SA','BBTG12.SA', 'AGRO3.SA', 'BPAN4.SA', 'BPHA3.SA', 'BRML3.SA', 'BRSR6.SA', 'BTOW3.SA', 'CARD3.SA', 'CIEL3.SA', 'CMIG4.SA', 'CTKA4.SA', 'CTSA3.SA'];

                function consultarCotacao(papeis) {

                    var arr = [];
                    angular.forEach(papeis, function (papel) {
                        var yql = 'select * from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol in ("' + papel + '")';
                        var api = 'https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=' + encodeURIComponent(yql);
                        var url = api + '&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=';
                        $http({
                            method: 'GET',
                            url: url,
                            timeout: 3000,
                            headers: {'Content-Type': 'json'}
                        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                            resultado = response.data.query.results.quote;
                            if (resultado.Name !== null) {
                                arr.push(resultado);
                            } else {
                                console.log(resultado.Symbol + ' não foi encontrado!');
                            }
                        }, function errorCallback(response) {
                            console.log('Falha na chamada do recurso.');
                        });
                    });

                    $scope.valores = arr;
                }
                $scope.color = function (valor)
                {
                    if (valor.indexOf("+") !== -1) {
                        return "green";
                    }
                    return "red";
                }
                consultarCotacao(papeis);
                //$interval(consultarCotacao, 5000, 0);
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="moneyController">
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Código</th>
                    <th>Cotação</th>
                    <th>Variação (RS)</th>
                    <th>Variação (%)</th>
                    <th>Maior cotação</th>
                    <th>Menor cotação</th>
                    <th>Abertura</th>
                    <th>Fechamento</th>
                    <th>Volume</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="valor in valores">
                    <td>{{valor.Symbol}}</td>
                    <td>R$ {{valor.LastTradePriceOnly}}</td>
                    <td ng-class="color(valor.Change)">R$ {{valor.Change}}</td>
                    <td ng-class="color(valor.ChangeinPercent)">{{valor.ChangeinPercent}}</td>
                    <td>R$ {{valor.DaysHigh}}</td>
                    <td>R$ {{valor.DaysLow}}</td>
                    <td>R$ {{valor.Open}}</td>
                    <td>R$ {{valor.PreviousClose}}</td>
                    <td>{{valor.Volume}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Mapeamento das colunas da tabela para o JSOn:

- Código => Symbol
- Cotação => LastTradePriceOnly
- Variação (RS) => Change
- Variação (%) => ChangeinPercent
- Maior cotação => DaysHigh
- Menor cotação => DaysLow
- Abertura => Open
- Fechamento => PreviousClose
- Volume => Volume

Arquivo JSON que popula a tabela:

```
{
    "query": {
        "count": 1,
        "created": "2017-02-22T12:29:35Z",
        "lang": "pt-br",
        "results": {
            "quote": {
                "symbol": "CTSA3.SA",
                "Ask": "2.07",
                "AverageDailyVolume": "6374",
                "Bid": "1.91",
                "AskRealtime": null,
                "BidRealtime": null,
                "BookValue": "6.24",
                "Change_PercentChange": "-0.06 - -2.90%",
                "Change": "-0.06",
                "Commission": null,
                "Currency": "BRL",
                "ChangeRealtime": null,
                "AfterHoursChangeRealtime": null,
                "DividendShare": null,
                "LastTradeDate": "2/21/2017",
                "TradeDate": null,
                "EarningsShare": "-0.37",
                "ErrorIndicationreturnedforsymbolchangedinvalid": null,
                "EPSEstimateCurrentYear": null,
                "EPSEstimateNextYear": null,
                "EPSEstimateNextQuarter": "0.00",
                "DaysLow": "2.00",
                "DaysHigh": "2.07",
                "YearLow": "1.46",
                "YearHigh": "3.29",
                "HoldingsGainPercent": null,
                "AnnualizedGain": null,
                "HoldingsGain": null,
                "HoldingsGainPercentRealtime": null,
                "HoldingsGainRealtime": null,
                "MoreInfo": null,
                "OrderBookRealtime": null,
                "MarketCapitalization": "78.99M",
                "MarketCapRealtime": null,
                "EBITDA": "136000.00",
                "ChangeFromYearLow": "0.55",
                "PercentChangeFromYearLow": "+37.67%",
                "LastTradeRealtimeWithTime": null,
                "ChangePercentRealtime": null,
                "ChangeFromYearHigh": "-1.28",
                "PercebtChangeFromYearHigh": "-38.91%",
                "LastTradeWithTime": "4:29pm - <b>2.01</b>",
                "LastTradePriceOnly": "2.01",
                "HighLimit": null,
                "LowLimit": null,
                "DaysRange": "2.00 - 2.07",
                "DaysRangeRealtime": null,
                "FiftydayMovingAverage": "2.03",
                "TwoHundreddayMovingAverage": "1.84",
                "ChangeFromTwoHundreddayMovingAverage": "0.17",
                "PercentChangeFromTwoHundreddayMovingAverage": "+9.44%",
                "ChangeFromFiftydayMovingAverage": "-0.02",
                "PercentChangeFromFiftydayMovingAverage": "-0.77%",
                "Name": "SANTANENSE  ON",
                "Notes": null,
                "Open": "2.07",
                "PreviousClose": "2.07",
                "PricePaid": null,
                "ChangeinPercent": "-2.90%",
                "PriceSales": "0.23",
                "PriceBook": "0.33",
                "ExDividendDate": "5/4/2015",
                "PERatio": null,
                "DividendPayDate": null,
                "PERatioRealtime": null,
                "PEGRatio": "0.00",
                "PriceEPSEstimateCurrentYear": null,
                "PriceEPSEstimateNextYear": null,
                "Symbol": "CTSA3.SA",
                "SharesOwned": null,
                "ShortRatio": "0.00",
                "LastTradeTime": "4:29pm",
                "TickerTrend": null,
                "OneyrTargetPrice": null,
                "Volume": "6800",
                "HoldingsValue": null,
                "HoldingsValueRealtime": null,
                "YearRange": "1.46 - 3.29",
                "DaysValueChange": null,
                "DaysValueChangeRealtime": null,
                "StockExchange": "SAO",
                "DividendYield": null,
                "PercentChange": "-2.90%"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Outro exemplo de JSON:

```
{
    "query": {
        "count": 1,
        "created": "2017-02-22T12:29:35Z",
        "lang": "pt-br",
        "results": {
            "quote": {
                "symbol": "BPHA3.SA",
                "Ask": "7.70",
                "AverageDailyVolume": "230233",
                "Bid": "7.46",
                "AskRealtime": null,
                "BidRealtime": null,
                "BookValue": "5.54",
                "Change_PercentChange": "-0.15 - -1.96%",
                "Change": "-0.15",
                "Commission": null,
                "Currency": "BRL",
                "ChangeRealtime": null,
                "AfterHoursChangeRealtime": null,
                "DividendShare": null,
                "LastTradeDate": "2/21/2017",
                "TradeDate": null,
                "EarningsShare": "-9.42",
                "ErrorIndicationreturnedforsymbolchangedinvalid": null,
                "EPSEstimateCurrentYear": "-0.50",
                "EPSEstimateNextYear": null,
                "EPSEstimateNextQuarter": "0.00",
                "DaysLow": "7.47",
                "DaysHigh": "7.90",
                "YearLow": "3.92",
                "YearHigh": "19.20",
                "HoldingsGainPercent": null,
                "AnnualizedGain": null,
                "HoldingsGain": null,
                "HoldingsGainPercentRealtime": null,
                "HoldingsGainRealtime": null,
                "MoreInfo": null,
                "OrderBookRealtime": null,
                "MarketCapitalization": "848.11M",
                "MarketCapRealtime": null,
                "EBITDA": "-296.97M",
                "ChangeFromYearLow": "3.58",
                "PercentChangeFromYearLow": "+91.33%",
                "LastTradeRealtimeWithTime": null,
                "ChangePercentRealtime": null,
                "ChangeFromYearHigh": "-11.70",
                "PercebtChangeFromYearHigh": "-60.94%",
                "LastTradeWithTime": "6:04pm - <b>7.50</b>",
                "LastTradePriceOnly": "7.50",
                "HighLimit": null,
                "LowLimit": null,
                "DaysRange": "7.47 - 7.90",
                "DaysRangeRealtime": null,
                "FiftydayMovingAverage": "6.39",
                "TwoHundreddayMovingAverage": "8.00",
                "ChangeFromTwoHundreddayMovingAverage": "-0.50",
                "PercentChangeFromTwoHundreddayMovingAverage": "-6.30%",
                "ChangeFromFiftydayMovingAverage": "1.11",
                "PercentChangeFromFiftydayMovingAverage": "+17.40%",
                "Name": "BR PHARMA   ON      NM",
                "Notes": null,
                "Open": "7.65",
                "PreviousClose": "7.65",
                "PricePaid": null,
                "ChangeinPercent": "-1.96%",
                "PriceSales": "0.41",
                "PriceBook": "1.38",
                "ExDividendDate": "5/2/2012",
                "PERatio": null,
                "DividendPayDate": null,
                "PERatioRealtime": null,
                "PEGRatio": "0.00",
                "PriceEPSEstimateCurrentYear": null,
                "PriceEPSEstimateNextYear": null,
                "Symbol": "BPHA3.SA",
                "SharesOwned": null,
                "ShortRatio": "0.00",
                "LastTradeTime": "6:04pm",
                "TickerTrend": null,
                "OneyrTargetPrice": null,
                "Volume": "268800",
                "HoldingsValue": null,
                "HoldingsValueRealtime": null,
                "YearRange": "3.92 - 19.20",
                "DaysValueChange": null,
                "DaysValueChangeRealtime": null,
                "StockExchange": "SAO",
                "DividendYield": null,
                "PercentChange": "-1.96%"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Publiquei o código em: https://github.com/fabiojaniolima/money

Comment: E o que você já fez?

Comment: Relacionada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/185159/como-localizar-valores-e-aplicar-atributos-utilizando-o-angularjs

Comment: @Fabio coloque tudo que você fez, o ideal seria colocar o `angular` que você fez até o momento.

Comment: Virgilio, o código não mudou, ele está postado aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/185159/como-localizar-valores-e-aplicar-atributos-utilizando-o-angularjs publiquei acima um pequeno trecho para não poluir muito a página, já que essas características podem ser consideradas ou tratadas independentes

Comment: Já tentou mapear seu JSON para um objeto javascript e fazer o bind no HTML com o angular?

Comment: Sim, mas não obtive sucesso. Front-end não é meu forte.

Comment: Fabio, quando você obtém a array, existe algum campo que seja sempre único? independente de quantas vezes você efetuar a requisição.. Por exemplo, acredito que o campo `symbol` seja único, correto? Se não for, existe algum outro que seja? como um ID, por exemplo.

Comment: Eu indicaria usar OneWay Databind e a cada 10 segundos como você comentou, zerar o array da lista utilizada no ngRepeate e carregar os novos itens no array. Mais: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/153646/para-que-serve-o-dois-pontos-duplos-no-angular

Comment: @CelsomTrindade o campo symbol será único

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Preserve os valores retornados em um objeto mapeado, cujas chave de propriedade seja a posição do papel no array `papeis`. A seguir, altere apenas o valor da propriedade de acordo com o retorno da API.

As seguintes alterações foram feitas:

```
$scope.mapa = {};
```

Um objeto é criado no escopo do controle para conter os resultados retornados. Note que não é um `array`, e que não é redefinido a cada ciclo de carga.

```
angular.forEach(papeis, function(papel, index) {[...]
```

O método `forEach()` provê uma propriedade extra, passada como segundo parâmetro da chamada - o índice do item na coleção de origem.

```
$scope.mapa[index] = resultado;
```

O retorno da consulta à API é armazenado no mapa *de acordo com o índice*.

E, na *view*:

```
<tr ng-repeat="(k, valor) in mapa">
```

O formato `(key, value)` em um `ngRepeat` permite que um objeto seja utilizado como fonte, as propriedades como chaves de valores.

A chave (que é apenas o índice do papel no array original) pode ser ignorada, mas o valor é utilizado para popular sua *view*.

(Adicionalmente um outro objeto-mapa foi criado, `$scope.prev`, para ajudar a identificar diferenças de valor entre a requisição atual e a anterior.)

Exemplo funcional a seguir:

```js
angular.module("money", []);
angular.module("money")
    .controller("moneyController", function($scope, $http, $interval) {
        var papeis = ["ABEaV3.SA", "BBTG12.SA", "AGRO3.SA", "BPAN4.SA", "BPHA3.SA", "BRML3.SA", "BRSR6.SA", "BTOW3.SA", "CARD3.SA", "CIEL3.SA", "CMIG4.SA", "CTKA4.SA", "CTSA3.SA"];
        $scope.mapa = {};
        $scope.prev = {};

        function consultarCotacao() {
            angular.forEach(papeis, function(papel, index) {
                var yql = 'select * from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol in ("' + papel + '")';
                var api = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=" + encodeURIComponent(yql);
                var url = api + "&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=";
                $http({
                        method: "GET",
                        url: url,
                        timeout: 3000,
                        headers: { 'Content-Type': "json" }
                    })
                    .then(function successCallback(response) {
                        resultado = response.data.query.results.quote;
                        if (resultado.Name !== null) {

                            if (angular.toJson($scope.mapa[index]) !== angular.toJson(resultado)) {
                            
                                if ($scope.mapa[index]){
                                    var clone =angular.fromJson(angular.toJson($scope.mapa[index]));
                                    $scope.prev[resultado.Symbol] = clone;
                                }
                            
                                $scope.mapa[index] = resultado;
                            }
                        } else {
                            console.log(resultado.Symbol + " não foi encontrado!");
                        }
                    }, function errorCallback(response) { console.log("Falha na chamada do recurso."); });
            });
        }

        $scope.color = function(valor) {
            if (valor.indexOf("+") !== -1) {
                return "green";
            }
            return "red";
        };
        $scope.markDiff = function(a, b) {
            if (a !== b) {
                return "bold-text";
            }
            return "normal-text";
        };
        consultarCotacao();
        $interval(consultarCotacao, 5000, 0);
    });
```

```html
<html lang="pt-br" ng-app="money">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <title>BMF&Bovespa</title>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <style>
            .green {
                color: green;
            }
            .red {
                color: red;
            }
            .bold-text {
                font-weight:bold;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
        </script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="moneyController">
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Código</th>
                    <th>Cotação</th>
                    <th>Variação (RS)</th>
                    <th>Variação (%)</th>
                    <th>Maior cotação</th>
                    <th>Menor cotação</th>
                    <th>Abertura</th>
                    <th>Fechamento</th>
                    <th>Volume</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="(k, valor) in mapa">
                    <td>{{valor.Symbol}}</td>
                    <td ng-class='markDiff(valor.LastTradePriceOnly, prev[valor.Symbol].LastTradePriceOnly)'>
                    R$ {{valor.LastTradePriceOnly}}</td>
                    <td ng-class="color(valor.Change)">R$ {{valor.Change}}</td>
                    <td ng-class="color(valor.ChangeinPercent)">{{valor.ChangeinPercent}}</td>
                    <td>R$ {{valor.DaysHigh}}</td>
                    <td>R$ {{valor.DaysLow}}</td>
                    <td>R$ {{valor.Open}}</td>
                    <td>R$ {{valor.PreviousClose}}</td>
                    <td>{{valor.Volume}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        
        <pre>{{mapa | json}}<pre>
        <pre>{{prev | json}}<pre>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Seria possível ainda piscar a célula atualizada com background-color?

Comment: @Fábio não vejo porque não - você pode armazenar os valores antigos e comparar. Eu vou fazer uma pequena alteração para demonstrar o comportamento.

Comment: @Fábio feito - você pode notar o efeito de negrito em cotações diferentes da última requisição.

Comment: Não daria para deixar de negrito somente se o próximo valor for diferente do atual? Minha ideia é quando o valor for alterado a célula da tabela pisca (tipo um efeito de 1 segundo)

Comment: @Fábio Este é é o comportamento (negrito se diferente) que este exemplo está utilizando. Quanto a efeitos visuais, você pode utilizar ng-animate, por exemplo, para definir o comportamento desejado - entretanto a explicação foge ao escopo da pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

## Use um dicionário

Para que atualize o `array` interno fazendo apenas o update dos itens, sem ter que limpar e regerar o `array,` você pode usar um dicionário que relacione a chave com o índice do item e atualizar quando o resultado trouxer a mesma chave e inserir quando não encontrar.

Sugestão baseado no seu código no Github. Eu utilizei o campo `Symbol` como chave mas você pode colocar aquele que melhor fizer esse papel, ou seja, que possa ser identificado unicamente nos registros:

```
    angular.module("money", []);
    angular.module("money").controller("moneyController", function ($scope, $http, $interval) {

        var papeis = ['ABEaV3.SA','BBTG12.SA', 'AGRO3.SA', 'BPAN4.SA', 'BPHA3.SA', 'BRML3.SA', 'BRSR6.SA', 'BTOW3.SA', 'CARD3.SA', 'CIEL3.SA', 'CMIG4.SA', 'CTKA4.SA', 'CTSA3.SA'];
        var dict = {};
        $scope.valores = [];

        function consultarCotacao(papeis) {

            angular.forEach(papeis, function (papel) {

                var yql = 'select * from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol in ("' + papel + '")';
                var api = 'https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=' + encodeURIComponent(yql);
                var url = api + '&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=';

                $http({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: url,
                    timeout: 3000,
                    headers: {'Content-Type': 'json'}
                }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                    resultado = response.data.query.results.quote;
                    if (resultado.Name !== null) {
                        var key = resultado.Symbol; 
                        if (!dict.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                            dict[key] = $scope.valores.push(resultado) - 1;
                            console.log('insert: ' + key);
                        } else {
                            $scope.valores[dict[key]] = resultado;
                            console.log('update: ' + key);
                        }
                    } else {
                        console.log(resultado.Symbol + ' não foi encontrado!');
                    }
                }, function errorCallback(response) {
                    console.log('Falha na chamada do recurso.');
                });
            });

        }

        $scope.color = function (valor)
        {
            if (valor.indexOf("+") !== -1) {
                return "green";
            }
            return "red";
        }

        consultarCotacao(papeis);
        $interval(consultarCotacao, 5000, 0, 0, papeis);
    });
```

Comment: Só uma pergunta, tem alguma forma de no primeiro carregamento não precisar aguardar os 5 segundos configurados na penúltima linha?

Comment: O `$interval` faz um agendamento, por isso que espera os 5 segundos antes de executar a primeira vez. Se quiser executar logo que carrega pode fazer a chamada antes do `$interval`. Atualizei a resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Como o @Rafael B. Marcílio sugeriu, vc pode mapear o json para um objeto javascript, utilizando por exemplo o JSON.parse:

```
var json = JSON.parse('[{
"symbol": "CTSA3.SA",
"Ask": "2.07",
"AverageDailyVolume": "6374"}]')
```

E no lugar de uma tabela estática, vc pode usar o ng-repeat para popular a tabela dinamicamente, como nesse exemplo:

[Documentação ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Código</th>
        <th>Descrição</th>
        <th>Categoria</th>
        <th>Preço Atual</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in materialList">

        <td>{{item.codMaterial}}</td>
        <td>{{item.description}}</td>
        <td>{{item.category.description}}</td>
        <td>{{item.currentPrice | currency:"R$ "}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Onde o materialList é o seu array que foi convertido do json, assim qualquer modificação na lista automaticamente altera toda a tabela

Comment: Ainda não consegui resolver essa questão. Atualizei o post principal com o link para o repositório no github

Comment: Tentei utilizar json.parse mas recebi um erro: angular.js:10837Error: JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "object"

Comment: symbol é a sua chave única, e você precisa adicionar aos itens apenas quando esse symbol for diferente dos demais, é isso?

Answer (score 0):

Um modo que pode simplificar bastante para você é o uso de [`angular.merge()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.merge), que faz com que 2 listas sejam unificadas em uma só, atualizando os valores das propriedades em comum.

Ou seja, a cada requisição que você faz, basta atualizar a lista, assim os campos atualizam automaticamente, veja:

```
$scope.valores = [];

var arr = [];

angular.forEach(papeis, function (papel) {
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: url,
        timeout: 3000,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'json'}
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        resultado = response.data.query.results.quote;
        if (resultado.Name !== null) {
            arr.push(resultado);
        } else {
            console.log(resultado.Symbol + ' não foi encontrado!');
        }
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        console.log('Falha na chamada do recurso.');
    });
})

$scope.valores = angular.merge($scope.valores, arr);
```

**Importante!!**

Neste modelo, por ele ser bem automatizado, você não tem controle de verificações. Por exemplo, se por acaso você receber uma lista e, após 10 minutos, receber outra lista, exatamente igual (em questão de estrutura), PORÉM em uma ordem diferente, o `angular.merge` irá atualizar, mudando a ordem também. Ou seja, se o objeto que era o primeiro vier em 3º na próxima chamada, ele será o terceiro objeto na nova lista, etc..

Se isso não for um problema, não há muito com o que se preocupar.

---

Se você deseja fazer uma análise mais profunda do objeto, creio que o melhor seja efetuar um `for`, analisar os objetos que atualizaram e efetuar a atualização "manualmente". Algo mais ou menos assim:

```
for ( var i=0; i < $scope.valores.length; i++ ) {
    for ( var in=0; in < arr.length; in++ ) {
        if ( $scope.valores[i].id === arr[in].id ) {
            angular.extend( $scope.valores[i], arr[in] );
        }
    }
}
```

Onde [angular.extend](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend) irá copiar os valores das propriedades de um objeto para o objeto de origem.

Deste modo você garante que irá atualizar o objeto correto ao qual os dados pertencem.

---

Fiz este [`plunker`](https://plnkr.co/edit/Z08CPU?p=preview) para exemplificar o cenário, já funcionando. Utilizei apenas dados mais simples e simulei o `request` através de um clique no botão. Basta clicar nos botões e ver as mudanças.

Comment: Fiz como sugerido, porém, ao utilizar $scope.valores = angular.merge($scope.valores, arr); não retornou dados na tela. O ng-repeat precisa ser alterado?

Comment: @Fábio não. Só certifique-se de que você não está limpando as duas arrays antes de fazer o `merge`, caso contrário você pode substituir as duas arrays e tentar fazer o `merge` com elas vazias, já que você está "zerando" a `var arr` dentro do `foreach`.

Comment: A principio não estou limpando, o código atual é este: https://github.com/fabiojaniolima/money/blob/master/index.html

Comment: @Fábio você pode montar um plunkr (ou outro serviço online) de modo que eu consiga mexer com os dados reais que você está utilizando?

Comment: Opa, no link do GitHub tem o código que estou utilizando, ele faz uma chamada a uma API do Yahoo.  Baixa o projeto lá que ele está chamando os dados para os quais estou tendo dificuldade de tratar.

Comment: @Fábio sim sim, mas eu estou envolvido em um projeto agora e onde estou nao vou conseguir montar um local para testar muito bem, nem tenho muito tempo. Por isso pedi para você fazer, ai eu vejo com mais agilidade =D

Comment: Entendi. Disponibilizei os fontes aqui: https://plnkr.co/edit/Lei3esodp6YSxMjKV9AX?p=info já o teste (preview) está em: https://run.plnkr.co/plunks/Lei3esodp6YSxMjKV9AX/

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57022/discussion-between-celsomtrindade-and-fabio).

Comment: @Fábio fiz uma edição na resposta. Acesse o link novamente e veja se deu certo! Deixei rodando um tempo aqui no meu pc e funcionou. Talvez demore um pouco por que, pelo que vi, os dados obtidos realmente demoram para alterar né? Mas acredito que esteja ok